# Host Card Emulation on Android

Tags: android

What do I need to do to emulate an actual VISA or MasterCard banking card using Host Card Emulation rather than a sample loyalty card? My code is based on android's sample code for Host Card Emulation (a link to this is given below).

https://developer.android.com/samples/CardEmulation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience on android card emulation and unfortunately I have to say that it is not easy as you wish. To correctly emulate a card like Visa or Mastercard you have to know what kind of technology is used by these cards, e.g., Mifare DESFire, Mifare Classic, etc..

Then, you need to know all secret keys that are used by the reader to access the data.

Then to finish you need to find a library o write it by yourself the code which emulate these the card behavior (e.g., Mifare authentication etc..)

Comment: So were you able to emulate a Visa or Mastercard? I tried changing the AID to match that of a Visa but it didn't work. I also couldn't find any Visa or Mastercard SDKs for contactless payment through HCE, any suggestions?

Comment: No I was not able. I had to give up because android does not offer much on that direction. Even by using card emulation problems would be related to all proprietary operation like the authentication